# Adding equation with text

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to add an equation in the line and it changes the formatting of text written after that like this.

```
It makes quadratic equation which is ax^2 \pm bx \pm c .\\ then by eliminating the constants
and lower order terms.
```

It changes the style of "then by eliminating the constants and lower order terms." to 
"*thenbyeliminatingtheconstantsandlowerorderterms*."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. For instance it seems that your in line math mode is not properly closed. Check for an ending math mode character missing (`$`).

Comment: In addition to what Ludovic says, do you have the mathematical part in math mode at all? Your input should read something like `which is $ax^{2} \pm bx \pm c$ then` (I'm not sure that ``.\`` is for.)

Comment: Please don't vote to close here until we get some feedback from the OP: they have only had a few minutes (at the time of writing)!

Comment: in addition to what Ludovic and Joseph have said, this input should have resulted in an error message noting the absence of the `$` signs that signal the beginning and end of math.  this error processing does add a `$` when it hits a math element (here the `^`), but since it doesn't know when to end the math, it continues on its merry way putting *everything* after it in math until it does hit an input `$`.  paying attention to error messages is very important!

Answer (score 1):

Just to 'close' this question...

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

There are principally two methods to write an equation surrounded by text:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Displaystyle -- in a separate line

It makes quadratic equation which is \[ ax^2 \pm bx \pm c,\] then by eliminating the constants
and lower order terms...

\item Inline 

It makes quadratic equation which is \begin{math} ax^2 \pm bx \pm c,\end{math} then by eliminating the constants
and lower order terms...


\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

[image]